# @Disabled and @TestMethodOrder not working

Tags: java, junit

First I couldn't get @TestMethodOrder to work, starting working on something else and noticed that @Disabled doesn't work either. I assume it has something to do with my dependencies/surefire plugin. I looked at similar posts but no luck

Here is part of my pom

```
 <dependencies>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Looks like youare mixing JUnit4 and Junit5.Make sure that you aren't mixing those in 1 test... I.e. accidentily using the `@Test` from JUnit4 will disable the JUnit5 annotations.

Comment: If this wasn't caused by mixing JUnit versions, please [edit] the question and add a testcase as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

`@Disabled` replace with `@Ignore` and `@TestMethodOrder` replace with `@FixMethodOrder`

then its working.

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class Check {

    @Ignore
    public void test() {
        //TODO 
    }
}
```